# Как реализовать сайт с возможностью добавления пользователями публикаций?

Tags: javascript

Как реализовать на **JavaScript** сайт с возможностью добавления пользователями публикаций без авторизации? Они должны заполнить формы, после чего нажать "Опубликовать" и другие пользователи смогут переходить по ссылке на эту публикацию.
Покажите примеры сайтов, можно куски кода показать

Comment: мне любопытно. А как вы видите ответ на такой вопрос?)

Comment: Изучите сначала, зачем нужны серверные языки программирования, а затем уже задавайте вопросы. JS предназначен только для **клиентской** части сайта, и никак не может получить чужие записи без использования серверного программирования.

Comment: задавайте вопросы, если что

Comment: @VladimirGonchar зря вводите людей в заблуждение

Comment: @Viktorov если Вы не лукавите, посмотрите мой ответ :)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ наверное, вы плохо поняли мой вопрос. Он был адресован ТС. Чтобы он сам задумался о том, что хочет узнать. После этого он успешно мог бы найти все нужную информацию. Он бы учился учиться. Научился декомпозировать задачи. Вы реализовали то, что просил ТС. Но так и не объяснили, "как". Имхо, это медвежья услуга )

Comment: @Viktorov это особенно при втором комментк, в котором по сути написано отневозможности задуманного)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ но второй комментарий не мой. Я так и не считаю. В любом случае, предлагаю не продолжать, мы все равно останемся при своем мнении)

Comment: @Viktorov от чего же, я так же считаю что все разжевывать нельзя, но тут, я посчиьал что случай иной

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ТС должен был задать вопрос по Node.js, а не по JS в чистом виде. Иначе говоря, какой вопрос, такой и комментарий.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar Вы уверены что прям должен? Как Вам представляется возможность спросить про то, про что Вы ни разу не слышали? И тем не менее я  в ответе показал как это можно было бы реализовать без написания собственной серверной логики.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это можно сделать при помощи своей серверной части или воспользовавшись готовыми бэкэнд хранилищами например `jsonstore.io`:

```js
let jsonstore = 'https://www.jsonstore.io/73c1a19569ef446af700cb080b193c15261edef0d89f258ef839bb5e78a5f530/';

document.querySelector('button').onclick = () => post({
  date: new Date().getTime(),
  text: document.querySelector('textarea').value
});

reload();

function reload() {
  document.querySelector('section').innerHTML = '';
  fetch(jsonstore + 'record/').then(d => d.json())
    .then(d => Object.values(d.result)
                     .sort((d1, d2) => d1.date - d2.date)
                     .forEach(addPost))
}

function addPost(d) {
  let date = new Date(+d.date).toLocaleString('en-ZA');
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.textContent = `${date} --- ${d.text}`
  document.querySelector('section').append(div);
}

function post(d) {
    let key = rnd(55);
    fetch(jsonstore + 'record/' + key, {
      headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'},
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(d),
    }).then(reload);
}

function rnd(i) {    
    var rnd = '';
    while (rnd.length < i) {
        rnd += Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
    }
    return rnd.substring(0, i);
};
```

```html
<section></section>
<textarea></textarea>
<br>
<button>post</button>
```